# fscanf not able to read the values

Tags: c, ubuntu, file-io, scanf

I am trying to read a text file using fscanf.I am working in eclipse in OpenCV on ubuntu.
Here are some sample values in the text file
0   5   7   0.547619047619048   1   0.0274509803921569 1
0   6   8   0.541666666666667   1   0.0313725490196078 1
0   8   10  0.533333333333333   1   0.0392156862745098 1

But all fscanf reads is zeros in the array.Here is the part of the code that reads the values

```
long double testd[1000][6]
FILE* fid1=fopen("file","r");

while((fscanf(fid1,"%Lf",&b))==1)
{

    printf("%Lf\n",b);
    testsamplecount=testsamplecount+1;
}

for (i=0;i<testsamplecount/6;i++)
{
    fscanf(fid1,"%Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf",
                &testd[i][0],&testd[i][1],
                &testd[i][2],&testd[i][3],
                &testd[i][4],&testd[i][5]);      
}
```

Comment: as @ouah says in a (deleted) comment you need `"%Lf"` conversion specification in `scanf()` for a `long double`; `"%lf"` is for a `double`.

Comment: I tried doing that.But its not reading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop consumes the file. Try `rewind(fid1);` between the loops.

**Edit:** alternatively, as an option maybe a little more laborious but twice as performant, do a single loop, reading until there is no more data.

Answer (score 3):

`testd[i][0]`, etc, is an rvalue. What you need is `&testd[i][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't move the file pointer to the start point of the file.
Use the library fseek(fp, 0, 0) or
Try close the file and then open again.